# A relative clause for this sentence with "let"

Tags: relative-clauses

I wrote:

> There was another manned aircraft with it, **which** Iranians let **it** go

When I tried to remove extra "it", it would be:

> There was another manned aircraft with it, **which** Iranians let go

However, it doesn't sound familiar to my ear. Is it a correct relative clause, if no how can I rewrite it?

Comment: I would say the omission is obligatory.

Comment: Yes, and it would be better with a determiner "the Iranians"